# Invoking custom plugin from Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins

I've authored custom plugin for jenkins. Is it possible to call it from Jenkinsfile (and how, because I cannot find the docs), or should I rewrite the logic in Jenkinsfile from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

Replying now, because I too struggled with converting my plugin to support Pipeline plugin and documentation was confusing and incomplete.

As it turned out, if you have a working custom Jenkins Plugin, there is little that needs to be done. Ensure, that your plugin supports at least Jenkins version 2.3, and make sure you have imported package `structs` from `org.jenkins-ci.plugins`.

Add `@Symbol("%desiredPluginName%")` (replace `%desiredPluginName%` with whatever name you want) above `@Extension` of your plugins' descriptor. Make sure that plugin name contains no special characters - otherwise you'll get nonsensical error messages on start.

Add `implements SimpleBuildStep` to your plugins' Step declaration and implement `public void perform(Run<?, ?> run, FilePath workspace, Launcher launcher, TaskListener listener)` method. Unlike `perform` from Step this method does not return anything, so if you need to indicate build failure, you have to invoke `run.setResult(Result.failure)` method, rather than simply return false.

This should be enough to get started with your plugin. Install it to some test Jenkins server and create custom Jenkins Pipeline project. On the main page you'll see

> (?) Pipeline Syntax

menu button. Click it, and search in the dropdown list for the plugin name you chose earlier. Once you find it, it should show default plugin configuration page. Enter all the parameters you need, and click `Generate Pipeline Script`. This generated code can finally be inserted into a Jenkinsfile.

If you don't want to see ugly `['$class': '', ...]` configuration lines, you can read further about `@Symbol` on developer guide, which has been posted here year ago, but for me the most difficult part was getting Jenkinsfile configuration code. Also, here's [a good example](https://github.com/jglick/wfdev/compare/pipeline) of steps, which were taken to convert regular plugin to a Pipeline-compatible one.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/DEVGUIDE.md explains in detail about how to make a plugin compatible with Pipeline.